# Compare array values and selecting specific one

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I need a bit of help with the below concept.

I have an array:

```
$values = array(
    array(
        'logId'     => 1000,
        'userId'    => 1111,
        'dateTime'  => '2021-01-04 08:10:50',
        'event'     => 'OUT'
    ),
    array(
        'logId'     => 1001,
        'userId'    => 1111,
        'dateTime'  => '2021-01-04 08:11:50',
        'event'     => 'IN'
    ),
    array(
        'logId'     => 1002,
        'userId'    => 1111,
        'dateTime'  => '2021-01-04 08:11:53',
        'event'     => 'IN'
    ),
    array(
        'logId'     => 1003,
        'userId'    => 1111,
        'dateTime'  => '2021-01-04 17:10:50',
        'event'     => 'OUT'
    ),
    array(
        'logId'     => 1004,
        'userId'    => 2222,
        'dateTime'  => '2021-01-04 08:10:50',
        'event'     => 'IN'
    ),
    array(
        'logId'     => 1005,
        'userId'    => 2222,
        'dateTime'  => '2021-01-04 17:00:50',
        'event'     => 'OUT'
    ),
);
```

I would like to loop through it and select the "first IN" and "last OUT" based on "dateTime".
So I should be getting:

```
1 | 1001 | 1111 | 2021-01-04 08:11:50 | IN |
3 | 1003 | 1111 | 2021-01-04 17:10:50 | OUT |
4 | 1004 | 2222 | 2021-01-04 08:10:50 | IN |
5 | 1005 | 2222 | 2021-01-04 17:00:50 | OUT |
```

How is it possible to achieve this?
Appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you have tried that does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would approach this is to:

1. Filter the RAW input array to the earliest `in` and the latest `out`. We don't need the rest of the results.
2. Re-format that output in the format expected.

The `dateTime` strings appear to be properly formatted time stamps (presumably from a mysqli database). Which is good because it means we can compare the timestamps with `<` and `>`.

**Solution**

```
// Define the filter array
$filterArray = [];

foreach($values as $log){

    // Set a reference to this userId in the new array
    $user = &$filterArray[$log["userId"]];


    // If nothing has been added for this person's IN/OUT yet then add it on here
    if(! ($user[$log["event"]] ?? null)){
        $user[$log["event"]] = $log;
    }

    // If the event is IN then check to see if this IN is earlier than the one already stored
    if($log["event"] == "IN" && $user["IN"]["dateTime"] > $log["dateTime"]){
        $user["IN"] = $log["dateTime"];
    }
    
    // If the event is OUT then check to see if this OUT is later than the one already stored
    if($log["event"] == "OUT" && $user["OUT"]["dateTime"] < $log["dateTime"]){
        $user["OUT"] = $log;
    }
}


// Sort by userId
ksort($filterArray);

// Define the output array
$outArray = [];

// Fill the output array
foreach($filterArray as $log){
    $outArray[] = $log["IN"];
    $outArray[] = $log["OUT"];

}
```

**Output**

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'logId' => 1001,
    'userId' => 1111,
    'dateTime' => '2021-01-04 08:11:50',
    'event' => 'IN',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'logId' => 1003,
    'userId' => 1111,
    'dateTime' => '2021-01-04 17:10:50',
    'event' => 'OUT',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'logId' => 1004,
    'userId' => 2222,
    'dateTime' => '2021-01-04 08:10:50',
    'event' => 'IN',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'logId' => 1005,
    'userId' => 2222,
    'dateTime' => '2021-01-04 17:00:50',
    'event' => 'OUT',
  ),
)
```

**Code without comments**

```
$filterArray = [];
foreach($values as $log){
    $user = &$filterArray[$log["userId"]];
    if(! ($user[$log["event"]] ?? null)){
        $user[$log["event"]] = $log;
    }
    if($log["event"] == "IN" && $user["IN"]["dateTime"] > $log["dateTime"]){
        $user["IN"] = $log["dateTime"];
    }
    if($log["event"] == "OUT" && $user["OUT"]["dateTime"] < $log["dateTime"]){
        $user["OUT"] = $log;
    }
}
ksort($filterArray);
$outArray = [];
foreach($filterArray as $log){
    $outArray[] = $log["IN"];
    $outArray[] = $log["OUT"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code exactly do what you want

```php
<?php

$values = array(
    array(
        'logId'     => 1000,
        'userId'    => 1111,
        'dateTime'  => '2021-01-04 08:10:50',
        'event'     => 'OUT'
    ),
    array(
        'logId'     => 1001,
        'userId'    => 1111,
        'dateTime'  => '2021-01-04 08:11:50',
        'event'     => 'IN'
    ),
    array(
        'logId'     => 1002,
        'userId'    => 1111,
        'dateTime'  => '2021-01-04 08:11:53',
        'event'     => 'IN'
    ),
    array(
        'logId'     => 1003,
        'userId'    => 1111,
        'dateTime'  => '2021-01-04 17:10:50',
        'event'     => 'OUT'
    ),
    array(
        'logId'     => 1004,
        'userId'    => 2222,
        'dateTime'  => '2021-01-04 08:10:50',
        'event'     => 'IN'
    ),
    array(
        'logId'     => 1005,
        'userId'    => 2222,
        'dateTime'  => '2021-01-04 17:00:50',
        'event'     => 'OUT'
    ),
);

$users = [];
foreach ($values as $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($value['userId'], $users)) {
        if (array_key_exists($value['event'], $users[$value['userId']])) {
            if ($value['event'] == 'OUT') {
                if (($users[$value['userId']][$value['event']]['dateTime']) < ($value['dateTime'])) {
                    $users[$value['userId']][$value['event']]['dateTime'] = $value['dateTime'];
                    $users[$value['userId']][$value['event']]['logId'] = $value['logId'];
                }
            }

            if ($value['event'] == 'IN') {
                if (($users[$value['userId']][$value['event']]['dateTime']) > ($value['dateTime'])) {
                    $users[$value['userId']][$value['event']]['dateTime'] = $value['dateTime'];
                    $users[$value['userId']][$value['event']]['logId'] = $value['logId'];
                }
            }
        } else {
            $users[$value['userId']][$value['event']] = [
                'logId'     => $value['logId'],
                'dateTime'  => $value['dateTime'],
            ];
        }
    } else {
        $users[$value['userId']][$value['event']] = [
            'logId'     => $value['logId'],
            'dateTime'  => $value['dateTime'],
        ];
    }
}

$counter = 1;
foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
    echo "$counter ";
    echo $user['IN']['logId']." ";
    echo $key." ";
    echo $user['IN']['dateTime']." ";
    echo "IN ";
    echo PHP_EOL;
    $counter++;
    echo "$counter ";
    echo $user['OUT']['logId']." ";
    echo $key." ";
    echo $user['OUT']['dateTime']." ";
    echo "OUT ";
    echo PHP_EOL;
    $counter++;
}
```

**output**

```
1 1001 1111 2021-01-04 08:11:50 IN 
2 1003 1111 2021-01-04 17:10:50 OUT 
3 1004 2222 2021-01-04 08:10:50 IN 
4 1005 2222 2021-01-04 17:00:50 OUT
```

In this solution I make and array of users and every user has the structure like this

```
    [1111] => Array
        (
            [OUT] => Array
                (
                    [logId] => 1000
                    [dateTime] => 2021-01-04 17:10:50
                )

            [IN] => Array
                (
                    [logId] => 1001
                    [dateTime] => 2021-01-04 08:11:50
                )

        )
```

And then I use a foreach to iterate the array and update the `IN` and `OUT` if I find the better one 
Feel free to ask me any questions

Comment: You don't need to compare with `stringtotime` because the `dateTime` format is a legitimate timestamp. All `strtotime` does is add to the execution time.

Comment: So what is the better choice insted of `if (strtotime($users[$value['userId']][$value['event']]['dateTime']) < strtotime($value['dateTime']))` ?

Comment: Oh,  I got it, I can just remove the `strtotime`, you are right, nice :))